# Is there an RFC or standard for "Envelope Journaling"?

Tags: email, exchange-2010, exchange-2003, rfc

Is there a formal standard defined for Envelope Journaling (or BCC journaling)?

I'm a software developer, and want to make sure I implement the journaling consumer correctly.  My model for reference is Exchange 2010 and 2003, but I don't know how common those formats are

Comment: Exchange is common in certain use cases, such as medium to large businesses; however nowhere near common enough to use as a yardstick.

Comment: Thanks @MarkHenderson - You read my mind.  That's exactly why I was hoping to find an industry standard or RFC

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft has published information regarding their journaling format

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb331962.aspx

However email journaling does not appear to be a formal standard